# ImageMagick Install Windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, imagemagick, rmagick

I am trying to install ImageMagick on Windows. What I did is install Windows RailsInstaller created my version and now I need to use ImageMagick but for some reason it doesn't work.

I took the binary source code and install and run it from this page but didn't seem to do the trick [Link](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php#windows)

I also try the following http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gEWAVlNCKhg but it doesn't work

For the first example In cmd all I have to do is the following command to my understand to make it work here what I get

```
C:\Sites\case>convert wizard: wizard.jpg
Invalid Parameter - wizard.jpg

C:\Sites\case>convert wizard.jpg
Invalid drive specification.

C:\Sites\case>convert logo: logo.gif
Invalid Parameter - logo.gif

C:\Sites\case>$ convert logo: logo.gif
'$' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Sites\case>
```

Then i saw this. From the https://github.com/rmagick/rmagick which state it include rmagick but then i run bundle and get this

```
Installing rmagick (2.13.2)
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension
.

    C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
checking for Ruby version >= 1.8.5... yes
Invalid drive specification.
Unable to get ImageMagick version
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/ruby


Gem files will remain installed in C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9
.1/gems/rmagick-2.13.2 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rmagick-2
.13.2/ext/RMagick/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing rmagick (2.13.2), and Bundler cannot
continue.
Make sure that `gem install rmagick -v '2.13.2'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Thank for any help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here yo go, to install ImageMagick and build the RMagick gem and make it all work.

Follow below steps:

1. Go [here](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php) mirror images.
2. Download ImageMagick of any version **except the currently latest release, which has some issues**
3. Install it with options: Add to PATH and development headers. **Installation path should not contain spaces**.
4. In the command line type convert -version to check if everything works. It should print something like:

   Version: ImageMagick 6.6.1-10 2010-05-15 Q16 http://www.imagemagick.org
   Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2010 ImageMagick Studio LLC
   Features: OpenMP
5. Install the [DevKit](https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/development-kit) if you haven't already.
6. Install the rmagick gem: `gem install rmagick --platform=ruby -- --with-opt-lib=c:/ruby192/ImageMagick/lib --with-opt-include=c:/ruby192/ImageMagick/include`

(Making sure the paths point to wherever you installed imagemagick)

It should print

```
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
```

And after a few minutes if everything goes right, you should see

```
Successfully installed rmagick-2.13.1
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for rmagick-2.13.1...
Installing RDoc documentation for rmagick-2.13.1...
```

And that's it. Just two more links that were helpful: [1 blog](http://phosphor-escence.blogspot.com/2010/10/install-rmagick-on-mingw-and-msys.html) and [2 blog](http://phosphor-escence.blogspot.com/2010/12/if-you-fail-install-rmagick-on-mingw.html) if you still can't install

Comment: Seems good but you actually need to `prepend` the imagemagick bin dir to path, not just add it.

Comment: The link is now broken.

Comment: The first one @SumitMunot

Comment: It looks like one of the issues with v7 is that the CLI has been renamed to "magick" instead of "convert"... so that broke some things for me (finding instead `system32/convert` per @john-pankowicz's comment below).

Comment: check here for mirrors with older versions http://www.imagemagick.org/script/mirror.php

Comment: As per @zrisher's comment, **on Windows**, need to change script commands from `convert ...` to `magick ...`. E.g. to check it is there, do `magick -version`. There no longer is "convert.exe" in the magick installation.

Answer (score 6):

- The first one is a path issue. There is a convert.exe that is getting
  found before the ImageMagick one.
- The second one is because you don't have working build tools.

Comment: pguardiario is exactly right. There is a convert.exe in c:\windows\system32. It is for converting a FAT volume to NTFS. It expects to be passed a drive letter. That is why it says "Invalid drive specification." I put ImageMagick at the start of the path and now not only did the ImageMagick test commands work, but I was able to install the Rmagick gem with no problem.

Comment: In current releases, need to change script commands from `convert ...` to `magick ...`. E.g. to check it is there, do `magick -version`. There no longer is "convert.exe" in the magick installation, so changing path variable will not help.

Answer (score 6):

How to install ImageMagick on Windows 8.1, as of 5/1/2017:

1. take a deep breath
2. uninstall imagemagick/rmagick/everything that's failed so far
3. make sure you have the DevKit that the accepted answer linked to
4. Don't download the current v7 of ImageMagick. I have no idea why, but it doesn't work. Instead download ImageMagick-6.9.8-4-Q16-x86-dll.exe from [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/imagemagick/files/im6-exes/)
5. Install, including the headers. Since it's V6, it includes legacy utilities already so you don't have to worry about that. **Install into your C: directory so there are no spaces in the path.**
6. Open up your environment variables. You know, System>advanced system settings>environment variables.
7. Find PATH in system variables, edit and copy and paste the large variable value into a notepad or something so you can read it properly.
8. Find ImageMagick's path, cut it out and paste it to the front. My PATH starts with "C:\ImageMagick-6.9.8-Q16;..." If it's not there, add it yourself.
9. Update your PATH with ImageMagick at the front.
10. You should be all setup, go into command prompt and type "convert -version". Rather than a "Invalid drive specification" result which drove me insane, you should see the current version specifications.
11. Bobs your uncle, you have ImageMagick!

Comment: `take a deep breath`

This was delightful and it worked beautifully!

Answer (score 1):

There is it better described:
http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/HowTo_install_rmagick_gem_on_Windows

Answer (score 0):

Install **ImageMagick** windows binaries from https://sourceforge.net/projects/imagemagick/files/im6-exes/, findout where is it installed

Like

> C:\Program Files (x86)\ImageMagick-6.7.9-Q16

or some other directory, depending upon your system...

And run following commands in command prompt

```
set CPATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\ImageMagick-6.7.9-Q16\include
set LIBRARY_PATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\ImageMagick-6.7.9-Q16\lib
gem install rmagick
```

Replacing

> C:\Program Files (x86)\ImageMagick-6.7.9-Q16

with directory where you actually installed Image Magick

Answer (score -1):

this is the only approach that worked for me:

http://rails.webintellix.com/2010/01/04/how-to-install-rmagick-imagemagick-on-windows/

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.