# gem install rmagick error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I know there are many questions about this error but I read several tutorials and SO discussions without coming to a solution.

I'm trying to install rmagick (I want to install Spree ecommerce for Ruby on Rails which requires ImageMagick and rmagick).

I'm working on Windows 7 (64 bit), Ruby version is: 2.1.5, Rails version is 4.2.1. and I downloaded and installed (in C:\ImageMagick) ImageMagick-6.9.1-2-Q16-x64-dll.exe and I also installed Dev-Kit.

I followed the steps that Sumit Munot suggested here [ImageMagick Install Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16996718/imagemagick-install-windows) but when I follow the step 6 I get this errors.

```
C:\Sites>gem install rmagick
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rmagick:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
checking for Ruby version >= 1.8.5... yes
checking for stdint.h... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/bin/ruby
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/mkmf.rb:456:in `try_do': The compiler
 failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/mkmf.rb:587:in `try_cpp'

        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/mkmf.rb:1067:in `block i
n have_header'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/mkmf.rb:918:in `block in
 checking_for'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/mkmf.rb:351:in `block (2
 levels) in postpone'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/mkmf.rb:321:in `open'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/mkmf.rb:351:in `block in
 postpone'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/mkmf.rb:321:in `open'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/mkmf.rb:347:in `postpone
'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/mkmf.rb:917:in `checking
_for'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/mkmf.rb:1066:in `have_he
ader'
        from extconf.rb:37:in `configure_headers'
        from extconf.rb:17:in `initialize'
        from extconf.rb:474:in `new'
        from extconf.rb:474:in `<main>'

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1
.0/gems/rmagick-2.15.0 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/extensions/x86
-mingw32/2.1.0/rmagick-2.15.0/gem_make.out

C:\Sites>gem install rmagick
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rmagick:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
checking for Ruby version >= 1.8.5... yes
checking for stdint.h... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/bin/ruby
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/mkmf.rb:456:in `try_do': The compiler
 failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/mkmf.rb:587:in `try_cpp'

        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/mkmf.rb:1067:in `block i
n have_header'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/mkmf.rb:918:in `block in
 checking_for'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/mkmf.rb:351:in `block (2
 levels) in postpone'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/mkmf.rb:321:in `open'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/mkmf.rb:351:in `block in
 postpone'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/mkmf.rb:321:in `open'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/mkmf.rb:347:in `postpone
'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/mkmf.rb:917:in `checking
_for'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/mkmf.rb:1066:in `have_he
ader'
        from extconf.rb:37:in `configure_headers'
        from extconf.rb:17:in `initialize'
        from extconf.rb:474:in `new'
        from extconf.rb:474:in `<main>'

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1
.0/gems/rmagick-2.15.0 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/extensions/x86
-mingw32/2.1.0/rmagick-2.15.0/gem_make.out
```

This is my path: `C:\RailsInstaller\Git\cmd;C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby2.1.0\bin;C:\Ruby21\bin;`
Do I have to add something to the path?

Comment: `DEVKIT_HOME\bin` must be included in the `%PATH%`.

Comment: I had a few very strange problems with this too. Lately I can only suggest you to learn linux and run ruby and especially rails only on linux hosts because its made for it and it performs much better on linux too.

Comment: see if this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4873276/i-cant-install-rmagick-gem-on-windows

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5811388/imagemagick-core-rl-magick-dll-not-found-or-how-to-install-rmagick-on-windo

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, had the same trouble and gave it a second shot.

- Remove your current ImageMagic folder and rmagick gem
- Install ImageMagick-6.7.9-3-Q16-windows-dll.exe from [here](http://ftp.icm.edu.pl/packages/ImageMagick/binaries/) and ImageMagick-6.7.9-2-Q8-windows-static.exe in the same folder (these worked while the most recent ones don't)
- in your console window `set path=d:\ImageMagick;%path%`
- gem install rmagick -- '--with-opt-dir="d:\ImageMagick"'

I installed ImageMagick obviously in d:\ImageMagick, so adapt for your situation.
This worked for my Ruby 1.9.3 under Windows 7, success !

Answer (score 0):

Set **`%DEVKIT_HOME%\bin`** in your *`%PATH%`* in the ***System Variables***:

[image]