# Complete Steps Install Ruby on Rails on Windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Can anyone tell me complete steps install Ruby on Rails 4.2 on Windows (Windows 10)?

Comment: Are you sure you want to? From what I've heard Windows isn't that well supported. At any rate, the documentation should have steps for you if it's supported at all.

Comment: Windows is great once you get the dependencies working

Comment: Seriously? You couldn't use google?

http://railsinstaller.org/en

There's even a video tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zLW9WAUOveE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about Windows 10, but we have it working on Windows 7.

[image]

Here are the steps on how to do it:

> 1. Install `Ruby`
> 2. Install `RubyGems`
> 3. Download & install `Rails` through [`RubyGems`](https://rubygems.org/)
> 4. Install any third-party dependencies ([`ImageMagick`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16996718/imagemagick-install-windows) & [`MYSQL2`](https://medium.com/@frontlineutils/installing-the-mysql2-rubyonrails-gem-on-windows-7-8-a028f44d87f3) can take some time)

---

Here are the specifics:

**Installing Ruby** is the most difficult part on Windows, mainly because you have to **compile** it before installing.

There are tools which have done this for you, including [`RubyInstaller`](http://rubyinstaller.org/) and [`RailsInstaller`](http://railsinstaller.org/en):

[image: .....]

If you're a total newbie, especially to compiling in Windows, you'll want to use one of the above. *If* you fancy the challenge, you could compile Ruby yourself with [`Makefile`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Makefile).

--

After you've got Ruby onto your system, you then need to get RubyGems. This *should* work pretty straightforwardly, although it *may* be the case that you'll have to play around with your system's settings to get it working properly.

Here is a [good tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WJlfVjGt6Hg):

[image: ....]

RubyGems is simply a way to connect *Ruby* with any of the "gem" depositories which are available. Gems are basically ["plugins" / "libraries" / "dependencies"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_(computer_programming)) for your Ruby install, allowing you to call them in applications.

[*Rails* is a gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/rails/versions/4.2.4).

If you therefore want to install Rails, you need to be able to get RubyGems working.

After that, you'll be able to download and install *Rails*, which can be done as simply as typing `gem install rails` in your cmd.

--

After that, you'll be able to add extra dependencies to your system, such as ImageMagick or Mysql2 to get Rails working with external resources.

This is the really tricky part on Windows, as since it's built with [`MinGW32`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MinGW), many of the core components of Ruby/Rails have to be built independently.

Ubuntu/Mac are preferred OS's for many developers simply because they support most dependencies out of the box.